# Printing out different color text with each button press?

Tags: python, text, printing, colors

i'm wondering how I would change my code below to make it so that it would be able to print out the statement "Hell yeah!" each time you click the button, but in a different color each time. I've been thinking of different ways as to go about doing it but it never seems to work out. Any help?

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def b1():
    jl = Label(master, text="Hell yeah!", fg="blue", bd = 3).pack()

b = Button(master, text="Press me!", command=b1, padx = 5, pady = 5, bg="grey")
b.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want random colors or colors chosen from an array?

Comment: At random. I can't seem to find how the heck to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by implementing a generator that returns a value from a collection of colors every time `next` is called on it:

```
from itertools import repeat

def get_color_generator():
    # This will return a tuple with the colors on each iteration
    COLORS = repeat(("blue", "red", "yellow"))
    # This will never terminate ('repeat' without a second argument
    # creates an endless generator)
    for color_set in COLORS:
        for color in color_set:
            yield color

color_generator = get_color_generator()

def b1():
    bl = Label(master, text="Hell yeah!", fg=next(color_generator), bd = 3).pack()
```

If the order of the colors does not matter, it is even easier:

```
from random import choice

COLORS = ("blue", "red", "yellow")
def b1():
    bl = Label(master, text="Hell yeah!", fg=choice(COLORS), bd = 3).pack()
```

[random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) returns a random element from a given sequence every time it is called.